# JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: bornDate

Tags: java, jasper-reports

bornDate is a java.util.Date field in my class, that is used to fill the collection represented by a List of Employees. So, when this second line is read:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(relatorio, parametros, beanCollectionDataSource);
```

this message appears:
JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: bornDate

Yes, I understand that is a type mismatch. But how can I solve this?
In the jrxml file or in my java class?

Answer (score 1):

In both, since the **class and name need's to match**

in **java** your need the method

```
public java.util.Date getBornDate(){return bornDate};
```

in **jrxml** you need the the correct field declaration

```xml
<field name="bornDate" class="java.util.Date">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```